# list is not updating after first call from get API

Tags: java, android

**get API link using retrofit and live data call the first time after some time not updating itself**

Call the function on resume in fragment 
LiveDataReport used in call retrofit and set the value mutable live
data
Model Fragment used in RecyclerView and adapter

I want get change on anything or updating in get API
immediate change updating RecyclerView list

***here my code***

> Java

```
    public class LiveDataReport {      
        private static LiveDataReport liveDataReport;        
        private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Model>> modelLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();        
        private ApiService apiService;

        private LiveDataReport() {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new BasicAuth("user", "pass")).build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                            .client(client)
                                            .baseUrl("http://someipaddress")
                                            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);        
            getModelLiveData();
    }
        public synchronized static LiveDataReport getInstance() {
            if (liveDataReport == null) 
                liveDataReport = new LiveDataReport();          
            return liveDataReport;
        }

        public LiveData<ArrayList<Model>> getModelLiveData() {
            Call<ArrayList<Model>> arrayListCall = apiService.getLiveDataJson();
            arrayListCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Model>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<Model>> call, @NotNullResponse<ArrayList<Model>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    System.out.println("//report change success Model");
                    modelLiveData.postValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<ArrayList<Model>> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("//report change failure " + t.toString());
            }
        });
        return modelLiveData;           
    }
}

public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private LiveData<ArrayList<Model>> liveData ;


        public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
            liveData=LiveDataReport.getInstance().getModelLiveData();

        }

        public LiveData<ArrayList<Model>> getLiveData() {
            System.out.println("//report call last update : getModelLiveData");
            liveData=LiveDataReport.getInstance().getModelLiveData();
            return liveData;
        }
    }

public class ModelFragment extends Fragment implements LifecycleOwner {

    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FragmentBinding binding;
    private LiveDataAdapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        recyclerView = binding.myRecycleView;
        adapter = new LiveDataAdapter();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Utils.isNetWorkConnected(requireContext())) {
            mainViewModel.getLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),new Observer<ArrayList<Model>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ArrayList<Model> models) {
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.setModel(models,requireContext());
                }
            });
        } else
            Utils.alertCheckNetwork(requireContext());

    }
}

public class LiveDataAdapter extends AdapterSkeleton<Model, LiveDataAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    public LiveDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> model, RecyclerView recyclerView, IsCanSetAdapterListener canSetAdapterListener){
        this.context=context;
        this.items=model;
        this.isCanSetAdapterListener=canSetAdapterListener;

        measureHeightRecyclerViewAndItem(recyclerView,R.layout.list_model);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ListModelBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.list_model, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(skeletonConfig.isSkeletonIsOn()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            holder.binding.appSkeleton.setShowSkeleton(false);
            holder.binding.appSkeleton.finishAnimation();
        }
        Model model = items.get(position);
        holder.binding.setModel(reportStatus);

        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
    }

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.item_animation_fall_down);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ListModelBinding binding;

        public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull ListModelBinding itemView) {
            super(itemView.getRoot());
            binding = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you notified adapter after getting data from api?

Comment: can you add the adapter code also?

Comment: May be problem is in your adapter code, post it for detailed answer

Comment: now add the my adapter code

Comment: May be you must call setmodel first before setadapter in onresume. Im not sure what is setmodel function do.

Answer (score 0):

updating list does not means it will shown into `RecyclerView` immediately . you have to manually update `RecyclerView` as well .

to implement this concept , create a method into your RecyclerView Adapter something like this one below

```
void updateList(List<POJO> newList) {
    oldList = newList;
    notifyDataChange();
}
```

so you will see that your RecyclerView will update , i know that we use livedata to do it automatically but in order to update recyclerView you have to approach this concept .